# resolve() in manual bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

Super basic question:  I am new to nodeJS as well as Promises, curious about if I am using the resolve() correctly.

```js
   _queryHelper( query, fields )
    {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            connector.query( query, fields, ( error, results ) => {
                if( error )
                {
                    connector.rollback( () => {
                        reject( error );
                    } );
                }
                if( results )
                {
                    return resolve( results );
                }
                resolve();
            });
        });
    };
   
// later on doing something like:
this._queryHelper( 'SELECT * FROM secretTable WHERE `generatedURL` = ?', stringIn )
.then( ( resultsIn ) => {
    if( !resultsIn || resultsIn.length === 0 ) {
        // do somthing
    }
    else {
       // do something else
    }
});
```

So the question directly is, when I use the .then(), am I bubbling out the results from the original promise query properly?  Basically I am trying to determine exactly where my original 'return resolve( results )' actually goes so that I can access the aforementioned 'results'

EDIT: when calling resolve( results ) from _queryHelper, am I right in understanding that 'results' is passed to my .then as 'resultsIn'?

Comment: Thanks, that was mostly what I was after, wanted to make sure that I was chaining correctly between my resolve( results ) and my .then( results ), and  it sounds as if I am.  Thanks for the logical catch too!

Comment: Since it looks like you are new here, if either of the answers you have below answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the best answer.  This will also earn you some reputation points here on stack overflow for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just asking if your code will work, then yes your results value should show up right where you want it to when you don't have an error.

`resolve(results)` will make `results` show up in your `.then()` handler.

I see three main problems with your code:

1. Your error handling does not work properly.
2. You have a logic problem when `results` is not defined.
3. You are missing a `.catch()` to handle errors.

You have a logic problem inside your `.then()` handler if there are no results because:

```
if (results.length)
```

will throw when `results` is `undefined`.  To be safe, you can change the `if` to this:

```
if (!results || results.length === 0)
```

---

You should also fix a problem you will have when there is an error so you aren't also calling `resolve()` when there is an error.  I'd suggest changing to this:

```
   _queryHelper(query, fields) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           connector.query(query, fields, (error, results) => {
               if (error) {
                   connector.rollback(() => {
                       reject(error);
                   });
               } else {
                   resolve(results);
               }
           });
       });
   };

   // later on doing something like:
   this._queryHelper('SELECT * FROM secretTable WHERE `generatedURL` = ?', stringIn).then((resultsIn) => {
       if (!resultsIn || resultsIn.length === 0) {
           // do somthing
       } else {
           // do something else
       }
   }).catch(err => {
       // handle errors here
   });
```

Comment: @ItsScience - I added info about two more errors you have.

Answer (score 0):

> am I right in understanding that `results` is passed to my `.then` callback as `resultsIn`?

Yes, that works as expected.

However, your code does not work, as you are always calling `resolve()` even when there was an error. This is a problem especially since you try to `reject()` the promise after rolling back your connector - but by then the promise is already resolved. You will need an `else`:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connector.query(query, fields, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            connector.rollback(() => {
                reject(error);
            });
        } else { // <===
            if (results)
                return resolve(results);
            resolve();
        }
    });
});
```

(or a `return` after starting the rollback). And you also won't need that `if (results)` test at all - you resolve with `undefined` anyway when it is falsy. Better just do

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connector.query(query, fields, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            connector.rollback(() => {
                reject(error);
            });
        } else {
            resolve(results);
        }
    });
});
```

---

That said, with Bluebird you should never need to use the `Promise` constructor when there is [automatic promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html):

```
const queryConnector = Promise.promisify(connector.query, {context: connector});
const rollbackConnector = Promise.promisify(connector.rollback, {context: connector});

function _queryHelper(query, fields) {
    return queryConnector(query, fields).catch(error =>
        rollbackConnector().throw(error)
    );
}
```

or even simpler:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(connector);

function _queryHelper(query, fields) {
    return connector.queryAsync(query, fields).catch(error => {
        return connector.rollbackAsync().throw(error);
    });
}
```